# scanf not scanning when in a function that is not main - C

Tags: c

If I put the stuff in getVectors into the main function instead of the defined one scanf works.

This code is supposed to first ask the what they would like to do with one or two vectors. Then get the vectors and do the math, but it goes as far as asking for them but when enter is pressed the values entered are not assigned to the vectors. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int getVectors(char choice)
{
    double vector1[3]={0};
    double vector2[3]={0};
    int i;

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 'd':
        case 'D':
            printf("Calculating the dot product between two vectors\n");
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            if(choice=='c' || choice=='C')
            {
                printf("Calculating the cross product between two                  vectors.\n");
            }
            printf("Enter Vx1 Vy1 Vz1 (separated by spaces)\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            for(i=0; i<3;i++)
            {
                scanf("%lf",&vector1[i]);
            }

            printf("Enter Vx2 Vy2 Vz2 (separated by spaces)\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            for(i=0; i<3;i++)
            {
                scanf("%lf",&vector2[i]);
            }
            break;

        case 'm':
        case 'M':
            printf("Enter Vx Vy Vz (separated by spaces)\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            for(i=0; i<3;i++)
            {
                scanf("%lf", &(vector1[i]));
            }

            break;  
        default:
            break;
    }
    return(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    char choice='a';
    double vector1[3]={0};
    double vector2[3]={0};
    double *theta=0;
    double *vx=0, *vy=0, *vz=0;
    char cont='a';


    printf("Enter M to calculate the magnitude of a single 3-D vector.\n");
    printf("Enter D to calculate the dot product of two 3-D vectors.\n");
    printf("Enter C to calculate the cross product of two 3-D vecotors.\n");

    while(cont!='n' && cont !='N')
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &choice);


        g=getVectors(choice);

        printf("Would you like to continue?\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &cont);
    }
    return(0);

}
```

Comment: Note that the local vectors in the function are unrelated to the local vectors in the main program, and when you call the function a second time, the values stored in the previous call are lost.  Under some circumstances, they might show up by accident, but not in your code because of the calls to `printf()` etc in the `main()` function.  Formally, the values are lost when the function returns.

Comment: So to fix that would i make the vectors pointers?

Comment: Most probably, you'd do something like: `void getVectors(char choice, double *vector1, double *vector2)` for the function prototype (since you only return 1 from the function and never use the value, you don't need to return a value, hence return type `void`; and pass the two vectors into the function). You'd then call it using `getVectors(choice, vector1, vector2);` which would pass the vectors in the `main()` function to the `getVectors()` function, just as needed. You'd remove the local variable definitions for `vector1` and `vector2` inside `getVectors()`. There may also be other problems.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this two changes in scanf.

```
 scanf(" %c", &cont);
```

and

```
  scanf(" %c", &choice); // space before the control string
```

When you are giving the new line character then that will be placed in the input buffer. that will not be flushed. So you have to handle that whitespace character.  If you are not doing that then `scanf %c` will take the newline character for that input. then that loop will be repeatedly going.

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: It does leave the loop, but values are unassigned. for the scanf("%lf"

Comment: I just went back on it after a few days and it is working now.